# Login not redirecting to the specified url on django

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I want to be redirected to the dashboard page in the website but I'm being redirected to a different url which is not specified in django url and as a result I'm getting `page not found error`. I don't know why django is not redirecting me to the `login_url_redirect` that is specified in the settings.py.

```
settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.UserBase'
LOGIIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/account/dashboard'
LOGIN_URL = '/account/login'
```

urls.py

```
url.py(in the main django app)
urlpatterns = [
    path('account/', include('account.urls', namespace='account')), 
]
urls.py (for the given app)
urlpatterns = [
     path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='account/registration/login.html', form_class=UserLoginForm), name='login'),
     path('register/', views.account_register, name='register'),
     path('dashboard/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

template

```
<form class="account-form p-4 rounded" action="{% url 'account:login' %}" method="post">

                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <h3 class="mb-4">Sign In</h3>

                                {% if form.errors %}
                                <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                                    Error: Username or Password not correct!
                                </div>
                                {% endif %}

                                <label class="form-label">{{ form.username.label}}</label>
                                {{ form.username}}

                                <label class="form-label">{{ form.password.label}}</label>
                                {{ form.password}}
                                <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary py-2 mb-4 mt-5 fw-bold" type="submit" value="Log-in">Sign in
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <p class="text-center pb-3">
                                    <a href="{% url "account:register" %}">Create an account</a>
                                </p>
                            </form>
```

I want someone to help me pinpoint the reason why I'm not redirected to this url specified in settings.py `LOGIIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/account/dashboard'`

Comment: Typo in LOGIIN_REDIRECT_URL (two i's instead of one). Also, your URL is "account/dashboard/" and the redirect URL is "account/dashboard" - the trailing slash can cause a problem if django hasn't been configured to append trailing slashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you have a typo on `LOGIIN_REDIRECT_URL` ? Shouldn't it be `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` ?